# ComboBox item too long

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Some of the items in my combobox are more than 20 characters long, I wrote this code to make them smaller and add "..." but it´s not working.
By example instead of "comboboxitemnumberthree" it would look like this:"comboboxitemnu..." to fit the size of the combobox

```
i=0;
do
{
    var item = comboBox1.Items[i].ToString();
    if (item.Length >= 17) // not sure about this part
    {
        item = item.Substring(0, item.Length - 6) + "...";
    }
    i++;
} while (i < comboBox1.Items.Count); //finishes when theres not any other item left on the combobox
```

Please let me know what is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Just paste this code into the `DropDown` event of `ComboBox`.

```
 Graphics g = comboBox1.CreateGraphics();
 float largestSize = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
 {
     SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(comboBox1.Items[i].ToString(), comboBox1.Font);
     if (textSize.Width > largestSize)
         largestSize = textSize.Width;
 }

 if (largestSize > 0)
     comboBox1.DropDownWidth = (int)largestSize;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at my machine to test but this should do what you need. Try to avoid do-while whenever possible. For maintainability.

```
for (int i = 0; i < combobox.Items.Count; i++) {
    if (combobox.Items[i].ToString().Length > limit) {
        // -3 for the ellipsis
        combobox.Items[i] = String.Format(
            "{0}...", combobox.Items[i].ToString().Substring(0, limit - 3)
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT: modified code. Was in Vegas at the time. ;P

Comment: This cannot work for another reason. You cannot change the iterator used inside a foreach. item is readonly here.

Comment: @Isaac: you should avoid a `do while` in this case because a normal `for (var i = 0...)` loop is simpler.

Comment: @Dan yeah i know but do while is better for me to understand when i re-study my code, tough i think it takes longer to debug

Answer (score 0):

You are not replacing the items in the combobox with the new string after the truncation

```
for(int x = 0; x < combobox.Items.Count; x++)
{
    string item = combobox.Items[x].ToString();
    if(item.Length > 17)
        combobox.Items[x] = item.Substring(0,17) + "...";
}
```

Comment: this works, i wanted to do it another way but it works, thanks

Comment: Your do..while loop seems correct, just replace the assignement to item with an assignement to combobox.Items[i]. The for..loop is just more compact than a do...while